# Why do 3 digit hex css colors convert to 6 the way they do?

Tags: css, styles, convention

I'm aware that the method to convert a 3 digit hex css color to 6 digit code is by duplicating each hex digit once, as below.

```
#ABC === #AABBCC
```

Why does it work this way? Why isn't `#ABC` equivalent to `#A0B0C0`?

Comment: Because apparently the language designers recognize how lazy us coders are ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the W3C spec:

> The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example, #fb0 expands to #ffbb00. This ensures that white (#ffffff) can be specified with the short notation (#fff) and removes any dependencies on the color depth of the display.

You can read more about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/

Comment: Best answer for making me realize that it is essentially so #fff doesn't translate to "very light gray".

Answer (score 2):

The reason is to be able to code the full range of colors (able to do both the highest and lowest color). For example, if `#RGB` became `#R0G0B0`, then `#fff` would become `#f0f0f0`, meaning you cannot code white. Conversely, if `#RGB` became `#RfGfBf`, then `#000` would be `#0f0f0f`, ruling out black. The system of `#RGB = #RRGGBB` allows for `#000` = `#000000` (black) and `#fff = #ffffff` (white), giving a full range of evenly-spaced colors.

---

Read more at:

- [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet)
- [W3 Website](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color)